# Stored Procedure refactoring

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am looking at refactoring this stored procedure as it seems that it is causing a timeout on the Azure DB using 100% of DTU capacity.

Does anyone have any suggestions how I could improve the SQL used in my stored proc?

Thanks

```
declare @value bigint
declare @secondValue bigint 

select @value = count(*) from [dbo].[myTable]
where ([Name] = 'something') AND ([Type] = 'paid') AND profilestatus = 'something'
and ExpiresOn >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

select @trialing = count(*) from [dbo].[myTable]
where ([Name] = 'something') AND ([Type] = 'avalue') AND profilestatus = 'something'
and ExpiresOn >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

select @value as firstValue, @secondValue as secondValue
```

Client Stats:

[image]

Comment: You can avoid doing two passes on the data (per Eldar S's answer), but the execution plan would help a lot. You can share it using [Brent's web utility](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)

Comment: To answer this question properly we would need to see both the table definition (with keys and indexes) and the query plan.  Failing that the obvious answer is to just put an index on the columns referenced in the WHERE clause.

Comment: You probably need an index `(Name, profilestatus, ExpiresOn) INCLUDE ([Type])` with the first two columns in either order

Answer (score 3):

I see you want to fetch two counts - one for each of two values of [Type], in this case a `group by` should improve your performance significantly:

```
select [Type], count(*) AS cnt
from [dbo].[myTable]
where ([Name] = 'something') AND ([Type] IN ('paid', 'avalue')) AND profilestatus = 'something' AND ExpiresOn >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
group by [Type]
```

You can incorporate that query into your stored procedure expecting two records in the result set.

Answer (score 2):

Your queries are simple and straight-forward. I see two things to review and consider.

First, how big is the table? Are there 100, 100,000, or 10eBIG rows? How much of this data has to be read in order to determine your results?

Probably a lot, which gets to the second issue: what indexes have been built on this table? If you have 1,000,000 rows, but only 23 of them have `Name = 'something'`, then an index on table Name would greatly improve performance. Conversely, if 90% of the rows are `'something'`, an index on that column would not help with this query. By and large, the purpose of an index is to help filter how much data has to be physically read when executing a query.

Things start to get complex with your filtering on four columns, as only one index will be used. Can a single index be built that would optimize these queries? It depends on what your data looks like. For further reference, you should review the topics of “sql covering indexes” and “sql cardinality”; google searches on these will find many, many articles and discussions on these important topics.